# Using the AWS cli to set the auto scaling group execution policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, autoscaling

I am using the AWS CLI to create my Auto scaling groups and Launch configuration.
My problem is that I still cant figure out how to set the Execution Policies as shown below

[image: How to Set the arrows from the command line]

Anyone got a nugget to figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`put-alarm-metric`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/put-metric-alarm.html#put-metric-alarm) on the CloudWatch Alarm to point to the Scaling Policy.

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for this, but it does not really answer the question. You gave a python solution, where Im trying to use the CLI. I suppose I could use the --alarm-actions, but even that is not very clear

Comment: Updated for AWS CLI. It looks like you point the Alarm to the Policy (rather than configuring the policy to be triggered by the Alarm).

Comment: That was the clue i needed! Thank you! The order goes: 1) add group 2) create policy 3) get policy arn 4) create aws cloudwatch put-metric-alarm <all the other stuff> --alarm-action <policy arn>